# How to plot two functions on one graph?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure

I've been given the homework to graph the function x^3 and 3^x in one graph.

Does anyone could help me with this exercise please?

Comment: Happy to, if you provide some code that indicates what you've tried and where it's gone wrong...

Comment: well that's probably something you could find in your very first introductory example to matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every time you call `plot` matlab will clean the canvas before drawing the new function, unless you are focused on a window where you called `hold on`, which will substantially tells Matlab to keep the old stuff and superimpose the new drawing.

```
x = 0:0.001:10

y1 = x.^3;
y2 = 3.^x;

plot(x, y1);
hold on; % without this one will delete y1 before drawing y2
plot(x, y2, 'r');
```

Comment: @Batsu `hold on` is unnecessary in this situation. `plot(x, y1, '-b', x, y2, '-r');` would have done the trick instead of two separate calls to `plot`. Also, it is probably a good idea not to encourage questions of the "do my homework" variety. The OP provided no evidence of any attempt to solve the problem which is against forum posting rules. Just sayin' :-)

Comment: right, using feeding multiple functions in one single call is probably better. But could also useful to know about `hold`, even more if you are using matlab from the command window as an "overpowered calculator", which is the typical approach of the introductory courses to matlab (and I think is probably @MarianoMendez's case).

Comment: @MarianoMendez anyway Colin is right, you should do a bit more of research before posting. [Matlab's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) (also the available launching `doc` in the command window) contains almost anything you will ever need about matlab functions, examples and tutorials.

Comment: @Batsu "overpowered calculator" - that made me smile. And I agree it is definitely useful to learn about `hold` for when things get a bit more complex. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

another option

```
p=ezplot('x^3',[-3,3]); set(p,'Color','red');
hold on; ezplot('3^x',[-3,3]);  title('x^3 and 3^x');
```

ps. Two `ezplot` commands are used with a hold on becuase `ezplot` does not support setting color directly on it in the same call. One must first make the `ezplot` then set the color afterwords.  Also, there is not way to pass more than one color at the same time. Hence if one to use `ezplot`, I did not see a way to avoid multiple calls.

Sometimes Matlab functions are not all consistent in how they work.

[image]