# MATLAB: How can I plot the Probit function?

Tags: matlab

I wrote the following code to plot the Logit function where beta = 1.

```
beta = 1
e(:,1) = 0:0.01:1;
e(:,2) = log(e(:,1)./(1-e(:,1)))+beta;
plot(e(:,2),e(:,1))
```

As far as I can tell that looks fine, but I don't know how to add the Probit function. I understand how to put to plots in one figure, but I don't understand how to generate data from this distribution. Is there some convenient way to do this in MATLAB?

Ultimately I'm looking to create something like the following, in which it can be seen that the Probit and Logit are very similar.

[image: Probit vs Logit]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot two functions on one graph?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507700/how-to-plot-two-functions-on-one-graph)

Comment: In this case, I'd use the alternative given in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507700/how-to-plot-two-functions-on-one-graph#comment18488846_13507868).

Comment: I realise now I put an ambiguity in the original question. I know how to plot two functions in one graph, but don't know how to obtain the probit data so as to plot it in the first place.

Comment: Ah. Sorry for that then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
beta = 1
e(:,1) = 0:0.01:1;
e(:,2) = log(e(:,1)./(1-e(:,1)))+beta; % logit fn + beta
e(:,3) = sqrt(2) * erfinv(2*e(:,1) - 1) ; % probit fn
plot(e(:,1),e(:,2:3))
```

As suggested by @patrick if you have the "Machine learning and statistic toolbox" it would be cleaner to use the `norminv` function, that is replace the 4th line by:

```
e(:,3) = norminv(e(:,1)) ; % probit fn
```

Comment: If you have the 'statistics and machine learning toolbox' you can :)

Comment: Sorry, should not have removed the comment, but the comment was that it may be possible to use the function `norminv` as well. This requires the correct toolboxes though, as stated. No pun intended though and the erfinv is actually what is used in wikipedia.

Comment: definitely a valid comment, and wikipedia should mention it :) I will update my answer